# MKAnnotationView Callout Accessory is not getting displayed in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

For some reason ever since I updated to iOS 11, my `callout Accessory` isn't being displayed for my annotations. I have a title and subtitle set up from data I query from my server, however I can't get the callout accessory along with the `.detailedDisclosure` to display.

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        print("viewForannotation")
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil
            return nil
        }


       // guard let annotation = annotation as? CalloutPin else { return nil }
        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView


        if pinView == nil {
            //print("Pinview was nil")
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView!.animatesDrop = true

        }

        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure) as UIButton // button with info sign in it

        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
       // pinView?.detailCalloutAccessoryView = button


        return pinView

    }
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? Any help would be much appreciated as I've been dealing with this problem for a long time now as I need the callout Accessory to display in order for me to segue to another view controller when my annotation pin is selected. Thanks!

Here's what's being displayed right now: [MapView Annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQf6z.png)

Comment: For me work just fine.. Try `let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure) as UIView`

Comment: @KosukeOgawa check out the image a added to the post above. The title and subtitle of the annotation are shown when it's clicked but the detail disclosure doesn't pop up which is necessary to perform a segue when it's clicked. I have a table view behind my mapview that is displayed when search is clicked, not sure if that's messing with the annotations or not.

Comment: Oh, Do you use `MKMarkerAnnotationView ` ?

Comment: @KosukeOgawa No I believe just `MKAnnotationView` then then `MKPinAnnotationView` when I create `pinView`

Comment: @KosukeOgawa I've been doing some debugging and I don't even think the my `viewforannotation` function is even being called for some reason, since any changes I make within it aren't reflected on the annotation

Comment: @KosukeOgawa Could be a problem with calling `mapView` instead of the outlet that my map is connected to which is just `@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!`

Comment: 1) You set `map.delegate = self` ? 2) your view controller is inheriting from MKMapViewDelegate? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037244/swift-3-0-pin-color-annotation-not-changing-in-mapview

Comment: I figured it out, it was a problem of where I was calling that function.....